# How to Access an ArrayList in a JSP?

Tags: jsp, jstl

I have an `ArrayList` which contains cutomer name details. In my JSP I am using session scope like below:

```
  <c:set var="CustomerData" 
        value="${ItemDataResponse.dataItemsList[1]}" scope="session"/>
```

- How can I display all the customer names in a drop down menu in my JSP?
- How do I access an ArrayList in my JSP? (tags like JSTL, html I want to use to diplay the data)

Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tune something like this:

```
<select name="xxx">
    <c:forEach items="${CustomerData}" var="customer">
    <option>${customer}</option>
    </c:forEach>
</select>
```

Comment: .. if i click anyone of the drop down menu data, the whole
          page should get refersh.What should i do for this?